# How do I do an explicit instantiation of a complex templated function? and related Intellisense error

Tags: c++, templates, containers

Update 1: Replaced code with code that builds standalone to make it clearer

Update 2: Partially fixed instantiation problem based on @Jarod42 comment but still failing

I have some code that wants to search a dictionary with a string key in a case insensitive fashion. The full code is below.

The code as shown compiles, links and works without any warnings, errors or problems.

If I uncomment the line that explictly instantiates the template then I get

**warning C4667: 'const std::_Tree_const_iterator>>> findKeyIC(const MyMap &,const std::wstring &)': no function template defined that matches forced instantiation**

Also, in the line of FindNameMyMapIC that calls findKeyIC intellisense complains:

**E0304 no instance of function template "findKeyIC" matches the argument list argument types are: (const MyMap, const std::wstring)**

I'm most interested in the Intellisense problem but felt the explicit instantiation problem could be related.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<std::wstring, int> MyMap;
const MyMap gMyMap = { { L"A", 0}, { L"B", 1 }, { L"C", 2 } };

// Cases insensitive comparison of two strings, return true if they match.
// Supports std:string variants and char*/wchar*.
template<class StrType>
inline bool StrIEquals(const StrType& str1, const StrType& str2)
{
    return boost::iequals(str1, str2);
}

inline bool StrIEquals(const char* const& str1, const char* const& str2)
{
    return (_stricmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}

inline bool StrIEquals(const wchar_t* const& str1, const wchar_t* const& str2)
{
    return (_wcsicmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}

// Returns an iterator that refers to the location of an element in a map that has a key equivalent
// to a specified key using case insensitive comparison.
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Reference, template<typename ...> class Container>
inline auto findKeyIC(const Container<Key, Value>& container, Reference const& key)
{
    auto  it = container.cbegin();
    for (; it != container.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if (StrIEquals((const Key)it->first, (const Key)key))
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}

// template const MyMap::const_iterator findKeyIC(const MyMap& container, const std::wstring& key);

int FindNameMyMapIC(const std::wstring& name)
{
    auto it = findKeyIC(gMyMap, name);
    if (it != gMyMap.cend())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing the auto in template definition and explicit instantiation with 'typename MyMap::const_iterator' but it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Being explicit about the map template parameters Compare and Allocate appears to solve the intellisense problem and combined with using the explicit const_iterator (previous comment) converts the probems with the explicit instantiation to an intellisense warning (function definition for 'findKeyIC' not found)

Comment: Realised that I was still misunderstanding how you do explicit instantiation,

Comment: Explicit instantiation that produces intellisense warning but no errors is:
template typename MyMap::const_iterator findKeyIC(const MyMap& container, std::wstring const& key);

Comment: Being fully explicit about Compare and Allocator doesn't change this

Answer (score 1):

> I have this code to explicitly instantiate the template:

```
MyMap::const_iterator findKeyIC(const MyMap& container, const std::wstring& key);
```

No, you declare non template function overload.

I think that intellisense is disturbed by "variadic" container whereas `std::map` is not.

If possible, I would change your map comparer to compare case insensitive, so you might use `map::find` (logarithm look-up instead of linear search)

Else, you might do:

```
// Returns an iterator that refers to the location of an element in a map that has a key equivalent
// to a specified key using case insensitive comparison.
template <typename Key, typename Container>
auto findKeyIC(const Container& container, Key const& key)
{
    return std::find_if(container.cbegin(), container.cend(),
                        [&](const auto& p){ return StrIEquals(p.first, key); });
}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks for spotting the explicit instantiation problem, that was misleading me. With that fixed intellisense complains in the same way as for the other example.

Comment: I attempted to fix the explicit instantiation and the new code doesn't work though it is at least now complaining about failing to match template during explicit instantiation, and perhaps gives a clue as to why Intellisense is failing. I've updated question to hopefully make things clearer

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on find_if, I hadn't come across that

Answer (score 0):

One can fix the Intellisense error by replacing the *auto* in the template definition with the explicit type and by explicitly listing the std:map template optional parameters *Compare* and *Allocator*.

Thus that part of the code becomes:

```
// Returns an iterator that refers to the location of an element in a map that has a key equivalent
// to a specified key using case insensitive comparison.
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Reference, class Compare, class Allocator, template<typename ...> class Container>
inline typename Container<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>::const_iterator findKeyIC(const Container<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>& container, Reference const& key)
{
    auto  it = container.cbegin();
    for (; it != container.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if (StrIEquals((const Key)it->first, (const Key)key))
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}

template typename MyMap::const_iterator findKeyIC(const MyMap& container, std::wstring const& key);
```

This code compiles and links with no compiler warnings or errors and no intellisense errors.

However it leaves an intellisense warning on the findKeyIC in the explicit template instantiation line.

*Function definition for 'findKeyIC' not found.*

Comment: Why do you want explicit instantiation?

Comment: TBH I don’t need it now, I was doing it to help diagnose the problems I was having. Now I’ve managed to get it building with no intellisense or compiler errors I can just ignore it.